# Launcher app that supports rotation

Tags: android, launcher

There are times when I would prefer to view my menu horizontally but the default home launcher app doesn't support rotation. So I am forced to use the default vertical view.

I need an android launcher app that supports rotation. i.e Supports viewing both horizontally and vertically.

(Android Version : 4.2)

Comment: There are really launchers not supporting it? Never encountered any (at least I don't remember). Is this the only requirement you have?

Comment: As @Izzy said, nearly any alternative launcher supports this. Nova, Apex, Zeam, LauncherPro, ... You really need to narrow things down.

Comment: The default Android AOSP launcher does support rotation. Are you sure you were using that or did your phone have some proprietary launcher instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Apex Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.anddoes.launcher)** would fulfil your requirements. Im using it for quite a while now, and am very satisfied with it. In its configuration, you can define whether it should support rotation, or alternatively fix it to either portrait or landscape mode.

Apart from that, even in its free version (the one I've linked), the feature list is impressive:

> • Customizable homescreen grid size and up to 9 homescreens
>   • Scrollable dock with up to 7 icons per page and up to 5 pages
>   • Infinite & elastic scrolling (homescreen, drawer and dock)
>   • Fancy transition effects (tablet, cube, etc.)
>   • Hide elements as you want (persistent search bar, status bar, or even the dock)
>   • Customizable icons and labels for shortcuts and folders
>   • Choose different folder preview styles and background
>   • Multiple drawer styles (transparent/opaque, horizontal/vertical, paginated/continuous)
>   • Drawer apps sorting (title, install date, mostly used)
>   • Hide apps from the drawer
>   • Lock your desktop to prevent accidental changes
>   • Enjoy homescreen gestures (pinch, swipe up/down, double tap)
>   • Advanced theme engine (icon packs, skins, etc.)
>   • Backup/restore settings and data
>   • Optimized for both phones and tablets
>   • Lots of other customization options!

Runs stable, never caused me any issues. Using it on most of my Android devices (Android versions 4.0 and 4.1).

Comment: [+1] Got myself the pro version after testing it for a while… never looked back since.

Comment: When it comes to the Pro, [Nova Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime) seems quite similar.